# No map displayed in QGIS Cloud

Tags: qgis, qgis-cloud

I'm using a free acount an QGIS Cloud and I've uploaded the files such as in this tutorial: https://qgiscloud.com/en/pages/quickstart.

The problem is that the legend shows the layers but the map is empty. What seems to be the problem?

The website is https://qgiscloud.com/cove_adrian/WebGIS_uat_Victoria/

Answer (score 1):

Your map displays nicely on my phone's browser. Try clearing your browser's cache or test with another browser.

[image]

Comment: solved. the problem was from a deprecated CRS. Switched to WGS 84 and it works.